# How to uninstall only one application from a package of multiple applications?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, moreutils-parallel

I installed the package `moreutils`. I would like to remove an application included in this package called `parallel`. I just want to remove this one application, I'd like to leave the other applications in the package/my system unaffected.

Is there a way to go about this using an `apt` tool? Or would I have to manually remove the binary and any associated configs?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a package-provided file in a `dpkg`-supported manner [by diverting it](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html). If you want to prevent *any* package from installing `/usr/bin/parallel`, create a general diversion:

```
dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/parallel.moreutils --rename /usr/bin/parallel
```

This doesn’t fully remove `parallel`, it renames it to `parallel.moreutils`, but the effect is the same.

Note that the `parallel` package (which ships GNU Parallel) does something similar to this to replace `moreutils`’ version of `parallel` with its own, so if you intend to use GNU Parallel, you can install that package and everything will be taken care of for you.

If you change your mind in the future, you can remove the diversion with

```
dpkg-divert --rename --remove /usr/bin/parallel
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't, without breaking the promises of your distribution. Debianoids (just like any other distro) deal with binary packages as integral unit of software. Deleting anything from a package renders it potentially broken. And it will definitely break packages that depend on moreutils to get parallels!

So, neither is there a Debian/Ubuntu way of removing just that one file, nor should you be manually deleting files from that package.